# How can PHP checkbox remember previous selection?

Tags: php, checkbox, checked

When I run code first time all checkboxes are checked. When I unchecked some boxes and I submit it unchecked boxes are again checked.

What is the best solution to remember unchecked boxes unchecked after submitting?

```
echo "<strong>Meno:</strong>";
echo "<br />";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_meno)){
  echo "<input type='checkbox' name='option_meno[]' value='".$row['meno']."' checked />" . $row['meno'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: Remember that unchecked check boxes aren't passed in as post data.

Comment: Use `$_SESSION` variables.

Comment: I have idea how can I do it but the code would be really long using isset or if/else

Comment: `.$row['meno']` - its filled out with names form one column -  SVK meno =  ENG name

Comment: Ok, the only thing I'd need to know is when you're populating the form will the database show if it's already been unchecked, or do you only want it to remember unchecked inputs say if the form doesn't pass validation?

Comment: If you're concerned about long blocks of repetitive code, PHP has an [advanced nifty trick](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) you can use. Whatever, your code has a hard-coded `checked` attribute. That's the attribute that makes checkboxes get checked (you possibly added there for that precise reason)—just omit it when you don't want it.

Comment: What exactly should I look for in the link?